# win32gui: how to get the status bar text of a window?

Tags: python, win32gui

I want to get the status bar text of a window! I'm using `win32gui.GetWindowText`, but I can't get the status bar text. I just get the title! How can I get the status bar text?

```
#coding=utf-8
import win32gui
# get main window handle

f = win32gui.FindWindow("TMDIForm",None)
print f,win32gui.GetWindowText(f)

#get child window handle of main window
ex=win32gui.FindWindowEx(f,None,"TPanel",None)

#get child window handle of ex window
exx=win32gui.FindWindowEx(ex,None,"TStatusBar",None)

print exx,win32gui.GetWindowText(exx)
```

Comment: What application are you trying to do this on? Most status bars contain more than one section. You will possibly need to investigate `msctls_statusbar32`.

Comment: The class of the status bar is "TStatusBar" and  I have get the handle of the statusbar  use SPY++ .but i can't get the text

Answer (score 1):

The following should help, you cannot use `GetWindowText` on a status bar. A status bar usually consists of multiple sub items. To access these use need to use `SendMessage` with `SB_GETTEXT`.

```
#coding=utf-8
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con

# get main window handle
f = win32gui.FindWindow("TMDIForm",None)
print f,win32gui.GetWindowText(f)

#get child window handle of main window
ex=win32gui.FindWindowEx(f,None,"TPanel",None)

#get child window handle of ex window
exx=win32gui.FindWindowEx(ex,None,"TStatusBar",None)

SB_GETTEXT = win32con.WM_USER + 2
SB_GETTEXTLENGTH = win32con.WM_USER + 3

sub_item = 0

sb_retcode = win32api.SendMessage(exx, SB_GETTEXTLENGTH, sub_item, 0)
sb_type = sb_retcode & 0xFFFF
sb_length = (sb_retcode >> 16) & 0xFFFF

text_buffer = win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(1 + sb_length)
sb_retcode = win32api.SendMessage(exx, SB_GETTEXT, sub_item, text_buffer)

print text_buffer
```

I have not been able to test this, as I was not able to find a suitable Window.

Answer (score 0):

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta

> If the target window is owned by the current process, GetWindowText causes a WM_GETTEXT message to be sent to the specified window or control. If the target window is owned by another process and has a caption, GetWindowText retrieves the window caption text. If the window does not have a caption, the return value is a null string. This behavior is by design. It allows applications to call GetWindowText without becoming unresponsive if the process that owns the target window is not responding. However, if the target window is not responding and it belongs to the calling application, GetWindowText will cause the calling application to become unresponsive.
>
> To retrieve the text of a control in another process, send a WM_GETTEXT message directly instead of calling GetWindowText.

2. https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89831/win32gui.GetClassName

https://github.com/certsocietegenerale/fame_modules/blob/fb7a6fb34124fa2ae026719a0f16767cab731c6d/processing/cutthecrap/cutthecrap.py#L66

```py
# hwnd = your TStatusBar or TToolBar or anything
buffer_len = win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0) + 1
text = array('b', b'\x00\x00' * buffer_len)
text_len = win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, buffer_len, text)
text = win32gui.PyGetString(text.buffer_info()[0], buffer_len - 1)
```